# Get import error for textblob in Spyder but can pull up in python

Tags: python, ipython

Pip install is working with other libraries. What is happening here and how can I fix it?

Any easy documentation I can read?

from textblob import TextBlob
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    from textblob import TextBlob

ImportError: No module named textblob

When I type this into ipython it is the only library that can't load. I just intsalled NLTK which I also installed through commandline pip and can import it into Spyder just fine. However it doesn't work with textblob

Weird enough if I open up my Windows command line->python

> > import textblob

I get no issue. What's going on here? My ipython has never had trouble importing a module installed through pip

Comment: You're not giving anywhere near enough information to make it clear what your actual question is